# hough transform curve detection with opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv, formula

I want to detect lines and curves with OpenCV 3.1, Python 3.4 and Hough transformer. I found a lot of websites but I dont understand how can I programing the formulae. I have this code:

```
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,200)
     for rho, theta in lines[0]:
        a = np.cos(theta)
        b = np.sin(theta)
        x0 = a*rho
        y0 = b*rho
        x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
        y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
        x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
        y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))
        cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)
```

for circle detection if found this:

```
x = a + r * cos0
y  = b + r * sin0
```

its enough if i change only x0 and y0 to

```
        x0 = a+rho*cos0
        y0 = b+rho*sin0
```

?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: to detect lines HoughLines and HoughLinesP to detect Circle use HoughCircles. To detect arbitrary shaped objects use GeneralizedHough Transform. To understand how the the how hough transform work for line see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4zHbI-fFIlI for circle red https://www.cis.rit.edu/class/simg782/lectures/lecture_10/lec782_05_10.pdf  generalized is also similar to circle detection.

Comment: Thanks, but can i use GeneralizedHough Transform with OpenCV 3.1 and Python?  I cant find informations about GeneralizedHough Transform

Comment: I think there is no implementation of Generalized Hough Transform in opencv for python but there are Generalized Hogh transform implementation in python only